# Save pointer to array in struct

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, local-variables

Save pointer to array in struct.
I would like to store the pointer to array of int into struct but I am having trouble.

Below my code with commentaries:

```
typedef struct _index {
    int *data;
} Index;

void adder(struct _index *s){
    int i;
    int arr[maxint];
    for(i=0; i<maxint; i++) {
        arr[i] = i+42;
    }

    //i got a gibberish
    //s->data = arr;

    //works fine
    s->data = (int *) malloc(maxint * sizeof(int));
    s->data = memcpy(s->data, arr, maxint * sizeof(int));
)

int main() {
    Index n;
    int i;

    //this method also works.
    //int arr[maxint];
    //for(i=0; i<maxint; i++) {
    //  arr[i] = i+42;
    //  
    //}
    //n.data = arr; 

    adder(&n);
    for(i=0; i<maxint;i++) {
        printf("%d-", n.data[i]);
    }//testing
    return 0;
}
```

when i make assignment, i got strange numbers:
117-118-119-120-12-0-22-2292964-0-2293008-127-0-129-130-131-0-0-0-0-0-0-138-0

but if i use `malloc` and `memcpy` all works fine

Comment: arr is on the stack, It is a local variable. Don't cast `malloc` result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got gibberish in your first case, because you tried to "return" the address of a local variable from a function through the pointer. Once the function finishes execution, the `int arr[maxint];` won't be valid. In other words, after `adder()` finishes execution, `int arr[maxint];` goes out of scope and it's lifetime is over. So, the (*returned*) pointer becomes invalid and using that further in the caller function will result in  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution:

1. As you've done correctly, using dynamic memory.
2. use `static` variable (not a good approach, but possible).

In both the aforesaid approach, the lifetime of the variable ( static `arr` array/ `malloc()`ed memory) is not limited to function scope and thus, the pointer to the meory will be vaild in the caller function.

Comment: Why static variable is not a good approach? I'm trying to understand this part :-)

Answer (score 0):

The array `arr` in the `adder()` function is on the stack and only exists as long as the code in that function is running.  Once `adder()` returns that memory is re-used by the rest of the program and its content overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

`int arr[]`  is placed on the stack and gets removed from the stack when it goes out of scope. So you will point to garbage.
It works fine if you include it in your main because that way it hasn't gone out of scope yet.
Malloc works because you allocate memory and not just place it on the stack.